# Spring integration - concurrent consumers, and routing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm currently delivering messages to a `publish-subscribe-channel`, which has a `task-executor` assigned, with a thread-pool of 20 consumers.

- These inbound messages describe updates to entities.
- We receive updates regarding many entities, in quick-succession
- Updates relating to the same entity must be processed in the order they were queued

Obviously, by allowing concurrent processing of the messages, this removes the guarantee of order of processing of messages.

What is an appropriate topology that allows concurrent processing of messages that are unrelated, but ensures serial processing for related messages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this [DispatcherWorker](http://mashb.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/spring-integration-based-dispatcher-worker-with-worker-queues/) is an example of what I'm trying to achieve